# Does anyone know why this python code is just returning a single letter rather than a full word?

Tags: python

```
import random
import requests 

response = requests.get("http://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000")
txt = response.text 
    
firstWord = random.choice(txt)

print(firstWord)
```

I'd like this to return one of the words in that mit word list, but it seems to just be outputting singular letters and I'm really not sure why. Any guidance would be super appreciated thanks everyone

Comment: Use `random.choice(txt.splitlines())`, the reason it is returning single character is `txt` is a single string containing `\n` delimited words, and `string` is iterable in python. With splilines you get a list of words.

Answer (score 4):

`random.choice()` returns individual characters when given a string input. If you want it to give you full words, you can run `random.choice(txt.split())` instead. This will turn the string `txt` into a tuple of individual words by splitting at every whitespace character, then choose a random element from the tuple (which will be a word).

Comment: More accurate explanation than mine, removed.